# How to remove old history/data and keep recent from Google chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I've checked the official options in Google Chrome and it l rooks like there is only option to remove RECENT data, but I want to remove OLD data and keep the recent. Is there any way to do this on Windows?

By recent I mean, data in past 30 days. By old, I mean anything older than 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

I briefly added Click&Clean (version 9.5.4.1) and it does the same thing as default Chrome behavior . It will *always* delete your most recent cookies and history and you can specify how far back to delete things.

The link to History Limiter no longer works but History Limiter Custom (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-limiter-custom/ibpfkplbhnbiklpjacjbaelahebmbmpp?hl=en) looks like it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Google Chrome's website history, press Crtl+H to bring up your history. There are checkboxes next to each link. Select what you want to remove and click the "Remove selected items" button at the top of the page.

In my opinion, the best thing to do is clear your entire browsing data and start fresh. This way you will be sure all old data has been removed from your browser.

EDIT:
Chrome plugin called [Click&Clean](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickclean/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod) may be what you are looking for. I have not used it, so I am unable to vouch for it. There is a section where you can select cookies to keep and cookies to delete.

Comment: I don't want to entirely clear it, because there are websites I still visit, but there is a lot of them whom I visited only once, and never gonna visit them again, for example forum threads, so I'd like to remove OLD data, but not recent data, I also have important cookies saved to keep my logged in and other stuff.

Comment: If you are relying on cookies to keep you logged into certain websites, I would suggest using a password manager such as Lastpass [link](https://lastpass.com/)
Using a password manager will allow you to remove all of your cookies and clear your cache, but still allow you to log int without worrying about forgetting your passwords for the sites that you visit.

Comment: I did some more research and found a Chrome plugin called Click&Clean. That may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For now, the only way around it is to use a Chrome extension like History Limiter: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpdjaigdefdamkfcgjhbmpjbhiejjkph?hl=en-US

Comment: History Limiter is no longer available.